# How to host a .NET website in the server

Tags: asp.net

How do I host a ASP.NET website on a server? I have created a website using Visual Studio 2010 as a frontend and sqlserver 2008 as a backend. What are the steps I should take for hosting the website on a server? Do I have to buy any licenses for .NET or SQLServer? If so, how much will this cost?

Comment: I would suggest using Azure or Appharbor, or some other IaaS (Infrastructure-as-a-Service) or PaaS (Platform-as-a-Service)

Comment: @ChristianStewart Seriously man, you're badgering his grammar?  He probably isn't from this country and doesn't know proper English.  What's the point of your question?  If he gives you an answer to the question you asked him, will that help you in answering HIS question?

Comment: @SOfanatic From my experience, Azure isn't for everyone... unless you really know the ins and outs of self hosting your own websites/web apps, he should probably go with an easier solution.  Azure is really for people that REALLY know what they're doing- otherwise it'd be very confusing for him.

Comment: @ChristianStewart what was the point of your first comment? It has no point.

Comment: @Carmine I sought only to help him with English a bit. I've edited the post instead. Apologies for offending you, I was not trying to berate him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always host it from your own computer with Microsoft's Internet Information Services. This is a solution if you are doing this as a simple project. You'll have to activate/install IIS by checking it off under "Add/Remove Windows Components".

But to be honest, I would take Carmine's suggestion and start up an Arvixe account. You can pay $8/month and have up to 6 websites at any given time. I use it constantly for demonstrating web projects for my company. The only problem I have with them is, as I mentioned in my comment to Carmine's question, their service is sometimes completely down. Today was a great example, I was doing some local work on my site, but of course many of my files and all of my databases are accessed via Arvixe's servers. They were offline for at least an hour and I had to start working on something else until they were back up.

Answer (score 3):

I use Arvixe (arvixe.com) for all my web hosting needs.  They are great, cheap, and offer .NET support.  Their administration panel is absolutely easy to use (creating databases, etc.).

Go to Arvixe.com, sign up with one of their ASP.NET plans.  They will email you FTP information on how to upload your file content, as well as information on how to log into your admin panel to create the database you need.  If you need any help with this process, they have a 24/7 live chat feature and they can help you immediately.

Comment: I've been using Arvixe for a while but I can't stand their downtime. Their servers are fast, but occasionally they are just flat-out down. They're great for miscellaneous projects though.

Comment: @Lopsided, I've never experienced this at all.  I have a job running that checks for website downtime every 5 minutes, and if it detects downtime, it will email me.  Only received one email in the past 6 months.

Comment: I actually purchased my own server about six months ago and haven't used Arvixe since then, so you may be right. I'm not sure what caused my downtime, but it wasn't my code because when it went down it wouldn't even let me get to the login page to sign into my account, or would be incredibly slow. Do you use Arvixe for ASP or linux? I've notice their linux interface runs much smoother.

Comment: @Lopsided I use it for ASP.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to host an ASP.Net site on the internet. You will have to research the [various methods](http://www.asp.net/hosting) turned up by searching to see what is best for you.